# Unable to use ng-include in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

Pretty new to Angular and doing a small pilot project using Angular 5 and Visual Code. I am trying to use ng-include and the template doesn't get displayed.

```
  src
     add-device
        add-device.component.html
        add-device.component.scss
        add-device.component.spec.ts
        add-device.component.ts
     edit-device
        edit-device.component.html
        edit-device.component.scss
        edit-device.component.spec.ts
        edit-device.component.ts
     templates
        device.html
     app.module.ts
     app.coponent.ts
     app.component.html
     ....
```

simple device.html code

```
<div>Include is working!</div>
```

add-device.component.html

```
<div ng-include="" src="'templates/device.html'">
    <div>More unique elements here!</div>
</div>
```

I also tried following

```
<div ng-include="" src="'templates/device.html'"></div>

<div ng-include="'templates/device.html'"></div>
```

Following gives error, ng-include is not recognized.

```
<ng-include src="'templates/device.html'"></ng-include>
```

Objective is to use device.html template code from both add and edit device components. I am using typescript to manage the project. When i look at the Sources in debugger, i do not even see device.html file in source list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Angular doesn't have a `ng-include` as AngularJS used to have.

In Angular, you can create a component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-device',
    templateUrl: './device.html'
})
class DeviceComponent {}
```

And then, instead of:

```
<div ng-include="'templates/device.html'">
```

you do:

```
<app-device></app-device>
```

Comment: How to dynamically use selectors, like in ng-include we can specify the file name.

Answer (score 1):

**update angular 7+**

1. create a class that implements OnInit
2. add the module in app.module.ts

   ```
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-device',
   templateUrl: '../views/device.component.html',

   })

   export class DeviceComponent implements OnInit{


   ngOnInit(): void {
   }



   }
   ```

   add in the view

   ```
   <app-device></app-device>
   ```