# Is it possible to include one HTML file in another in Angular (not AngularJS)?

Tags: html, angular

I am developing a web application using Microsoft .NET MVC. As the default CSHTML views are not always responsive enough, there are some pages implemented in Angular. The rendered CSHTML page pretty much only includes a directive to invoke an Angular component, and Angular takes care of the rest.

Now, one of the Angular pages looks like its HTML template is going to get quite long. We're talking about almost a thousand lines of HTML code here. That's just the HTML template, not the Angular component handling it.

So I thought it would be better for development and maintenance to split the template into several HTML files, where the main HTML file would include other HTML files. But this doesn't seem to be possible.

Googling for "include HTML file in another in Angular" returned results about using the <ng-include> directive, but unfortunately that seems to only have been supported in the original AngularJS, not in the new Angular. At least the examples I used didn't work.

Is this somehow possible in Angular, or do I have to actually make the included HTML files into separate components?

Comment: I think it should help you) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555286/unable-to-use-ng-include-in-angular-5/48555420

Comment: You can move your html into many new components.

Comment: Please do not tag your question angularjs if you specifically mention that it is not angularjs related

Comment: Why bother with doing it in Angular? Just use partial views and compose them in a single view.

Comment: The reason for using Angular is that the page itself uses Angular for its working logic. It's not as if I were using Angular solely to include one HTML file in another. I already know how to do that in plain CSHTML.
How it works is that the controller returns a CSHTML file which consists of little more than an Angular <myApp> directive. This tells Angular to load its HTML template which contains the main content. It is this template that is going to grow to almost a thousand lines.

Comment: I got it to work by using a separate Angular component. Passing data between the two components wasn't exactly trivial, but I got it to work using a service that is injected into both components. At first I was puzzled because the main component passed data to the child component all OK but the child component didn't react to it. Then I realised I had injected the child component into the service instead of the other way around. I presume the service was passing the data to a different instance of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

```
const template = `
  <div> Your template here! </div> 
`;

export default template;


import html from 'template.html'
```

Then

```
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

And

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. This is because the included template is not just static HTML, it also contains Angular mark-up that is controlled by the main Angular component.
I haven't tried this yet, would it work or would it just include the Angular mark-up in the included HTML file as literal static HTML?

Comment: If it contains Angular logic , you needs separate it into components