# How to use an HTML code in another component in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to re-use my HTML code in other components. But I could not find a way to do so.

I have a component written called custom-grid.
This folder contains 2 files: `custom-grid.component.html` and `custom-grid.component.ts`

`custome-grid.component.ts` contains the following code:

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit} from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "custom-grid",
    templateUrl: "./custom-grid.component.html";
})

export class CustomGridComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){
       
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

}
```

`custom-grid.component.html` consists the following code:

```
<div id="myGrid">
  <GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="*,*,*,*">
     <!-- some code -->
  </GridLayout>
</div>
```

Now, I want to call this component in several places. For that, I do this on my `ts` files:

```
import { CustomGridComponent } from "../custom-grid/custom-grid.component.ts"
```

and in those HTML files, I just call:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="some test"> </Label>
    <custom-grid> </custom-grid>
</StackLayout>
```

And this does not work and gives out the following error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR: ERROR {
"originalStack": "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [object Object] is not a valid
 View instance.\nError: [object Object] is not a valid View instance.\n    at new
 ZoneAwareError (file:///app/vendor.js:153110:33)\n    at StackLayout._addView
 (file:///app/vendor.js:118087:19)\n    at StackLayout.addChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:129052:14)\n    at StackLayout.addChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:129169:15)\n    at ViewUtil.insertToLayout 
(file:///app/vendor.js:95036:20)\n    at ViewUtil.addToVisualTree 
(file:///app/vendor.js:95017:18)\n    at ViewUtil.insertChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:94977:18)\n    at EmulatedRenderer.appendChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:95314:23)\n    at EmulatedRenderer.appendChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:95575:15)\n    at nativeAppendChild 
(file:///app/vendor.js:51151:18)\n    at nativeAppendOrInsertBefore 
(file:///app/vendor.js:51162:9)\n    at appendChild (file:///app/vendor.js:51252:13)\n  
  at ɵɵelementStart (file: 
node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:14562:0)\n    at Module.<…>
```

If I am doing it wrong please correct me OR any other possible way to do this would work just fine.
Any kind of help would be useful. Thank you in advance :)

PS: I have tried this also
[Unable to use ng-include in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555286/unable-to-use-ng-include-in-angular-5/48555420)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you declared the component correctly in app.module?
Anyway -

1. You don't have to import it in the TS where you want implement in in the HTML.
2. This way will reuse the entire component, not just the HTML.
3. If you only want the HTML you can just give its path in the selector of the second component, like that:

`

```
@Component({
selector: "second-component",
    templateUrl: "../..{the right path}/custom-grid.component.html";
})

export class SecondComponent {
    constructor(){
}
```